# запись в файл или сохранить?

Tags: c#

Запись текста в файл или сохранение его, это по сути одно и тоже ? Но какой метод будет работать быстрее, 1-й или 2-й ?
Разница между `TextWriter` и `File.WriteAllText` и какой метод будет работать быстрее

Comment: А где вы видите два метода? Это один и тот же метод.

Comment: Ты имеешь в виду добавление текста и перезаписать новый?

Comment: @VladD можно отдельно записывать в файловый поток и закрывать его.

Comment: допустим, имелось в виду -`WriteAllText`  как первый метод а второй тогда что? `writeallbytes` ?

Comment: @Alex78191: Хм. Что из этого запись текста в файл, а что сохранение?

Comment: @VladD `FileStream` сохраняется в файл при вызове метода `Close()` или `Dispose()`.

Comment: @Alex78191: Ну, не совсем так, он же просто буферизированный, так что сохраняется по кускам по мере заполнения буфера. Но я всё равно не понимаю разницы между записью и сохранением, мне казалось, что это синонимы. И я всё ещё не понимаю, какой именно код имел в виду ТС под словом «запись», а какой под «сохранение». Если вы его поняли, ваш хрустальный шар работает лучше моего.

Comment: @VladD я понимаю как запись в поток и сохранение буфера потока. Чтобы сохранить поток его нужно закрыть или вызвать метод Flush() для записи буфера.

Comment: Для автоматического сброса буфера нужно использовать StreamWriter.AutoFlush https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Alex78191: Имеет смысл подождать комментарии ТС по этому поводу. У меня есть подозрение, что он спрашивает о разнице между `TextWriter` и `File.WriteAllText`. Но это, конечно, гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @VladD да! о разнице между TextWriter и File.WriteAllText и спрашиваю

Comment: @tube: Ну, теперь понятно. Тогда вы отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте эту информацию туда. А то так его закрыли, потому что было ничего не понятно. (И если вы его отредактируете, его переоткроют.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот реализация [`File.WriteAllText`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,867), с выброшенными проверками параметров:

```
public static void WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
{
    InternalWriteAllText(path, contents, encoding, true);
}

private static void InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, bool checkHost)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding, StreamWriter.DefaultBufferSize, checkHost))
        sw.Write(contents);
}
```

`StreamWriter` - это наследник `TextWriter` для записи в `Stream`.

`File.WriteAllText` внутри просто открывает `TextWriter` и пишет через него в поток. Так что разницы между этими двумя способами записи нет - это, по сути, два разных варианта вызова одного и того же способа :)